# Extending Ruby with C++?

Tags: c++, ruby

Is there any way to pass Ruby objects to a C++ application ? I have never done that kind of thing before and was wondering if that would be possible. Would it require to modify the Ruby core code ?

Comment: When Ruby gets too slow, I think it is being extended with C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and no, respectively.

Ruby is written in C. C++ is, by design, C-compatible.

All objects in Ruby are held by a VALUE object (which is a `union` type), which can be passed around quite easily.

Any directions you find for extending Ruby with C apply in C++ with little modification. Alternatively, you can use something like SWIG to simplify writing your extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Ruby with C++ is not a problem. Basically the only thing you need to remember when writing your extension is to declare an init method of your extension as extern "C", like so:

extern "C" void Init_your_extension() {
  // ...
}

I recently had to expose a C++ function to my ruby code, you can find the code here if you want (its just basic stuff, so I think it will be good to get you started): http://github.com/psyho/aspell_edit_dist

Answer (score 1):

The [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html) book has some details on accessing Ruby from C. I am not sure how current the documentation is though. This [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20091003005056/coaxialhost.com/tutorials/writing_ruby_extensions.html) describes the Ruby C API as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can build Ruby extensions in C++ using Rice, take a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-extendruby/